# ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager::CreateVirtualSmartCard the PIN is not set correctly

Tags: c++, tpm

I follow this [thread](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/400481-cocreateinstanceasadmin-how-initialize-com-on-thread/) to create TPM Vistual Smnart Card, after run the app the virtual smart card created and could see in Device Manager, but when I try to insert the PIN `123456789` to authenticate show the PIN is not correct

```
#include "Tpmvscmgr.h"    
#include  "StrSafe.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "Vscmgr.lib")
#include <Windows.h>

HRESULT CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin(HWND hwnd, REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, __out void ** ppv)
{
 BIND_OPTS3 bo;
 WCHAR  wszCLSID[50];
 WCHAR  wszMonikerName[300];

 StringFromGUID2(rclsid, wszCLSID, sizeof(wszCLSID) / sizeof(wszCLSID[0]));
 HRESULT hr = StringCchPrintfW(wszMonikerName, sizeof(wszMonikerName) / sizeof(wszMonikerName[0]), L"Elevation:Administrator!new:%s", wszCLSID);
 if (FAILED(hr))
  return hr;
 memset(&bo, 0, sizeof(bo));
 bo.cbStruct = sizeof(bo);
 bo.hwnd = hwnd;
 bo.dwClassContext = CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;
 return CoGetObject(wszMonikerName, &bo, riid, ppv);
}

int main()
{
 HRESULT hr = S_OK;
 HWND hwnd = NULL;
 ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager *pObj = NULL;
 CoInitialize(NULL);
 hr = CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin(
  hwnd,
  CLSID_TpmVirtualSmartCardManager,
  IID_ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager,
  (void**)&pObj);


 //ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager *pObj = NULL;
 LPWSTR friendly = L"Friendly";
 LPWSTR out = L"";
 BYTE pin[] = "123456789";
 DWORD size = sizeof(pin);
 BOOL boot;

 hr = pObj->CreateVirtualSmartCard(friendly, TPMVSC_DEFAULT_ADMIN_ALGORITHM_ID, pin, size, NULL, 0, pin, size, pin, size, false, NULL, &out, &boot);

 return 0;
}
```

Any one has any idea what the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The fourth parameter to `CreateVirtualSmartCard()` [must be 24](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tpmvsc/3bd5c84c-b434-4a78-ad74-6c093355fb0a?redirectedfrom=MSDN). It shouldn't be the same thing as PIN anyway.
- `sizeof(pin)` will return 10 in this case, because the null terminator is included in computing the size. Is this what TpmVscMgr does as well?

Comment: Thanks, yes I knew about size=24, I forgot to update here. But you right we don't need pass the null terminator. after I remove the last char it's working properly :)